# how to work out the format with hours

Tags: php, arrays

I need some help with set up the date format.

I'm still trying to find out how I can set up the format to the next day, the day two and the day three date when I work out with the hours.

Example: I set up the date format from today and the time is 10:00 AM, 11:00 AM, 12:00 PM, the format is 20140424100000, 20140424110000, 20140424120000 and so on until when I reaction to the 12:00 AM, I want to set up the format to the next day 20140425000000, 20140425003000, 20140425020000, 20140425023000 until when I reaction to the next 12:00 AM I want to set up the new format to the day two 20140426000000, 20140426003000, 20140426010000.

My problem is when I'm parsing the list of time strings from my script, how I can work out the format with the date and the time?

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
$errmsg_arr = array();
$errflag = false;
include ('simple_html_dom.php');

foreach($html->find('p[id=links]') as $element)
{
  $program_list[ $count ] = array();
  $id_split = explode("?", $element->plaintext);
  $id_split = explode("&", $link_split[1]);
  $channels = explode("channels=",$id_split[0]);
  $channels = $channels[1];
  $id = explode("id=",$id_split[1]);
  $id = $id[1];
  $html_two = file_get_html("http://www.mysite.com/myscript.php?getime);

  //time1
  $time1 = $html_two->find('span[id=time1]',0)->plaintext;

  $hoursMinutes = explode(":", $time1[0]);
  $hours = $hoursMinutes[0];
  $minutes = $hoursMinutes[1];

  $time1 = explode(" ", $time1);
  $hoursMinutes = explode(":", $time1[0]);
  $hours = $hoursMinutes[0];
  $minutes = $hoursMinutes[1];


  //time2
  $time2 = $html_two->find('span[id=time2]',0)->plaintext;

  $hoursMinutes = explode(":", $time2[0]);
  $hours = $hoursMinutes[0];
  $minutes = $hoursMinutes[1];

  $time2 = explode(" ", $time2);
  $hoursMinutes = explode(":", $time2[0]);
  $hours = $hoursMinutes[0];
  $minutes = $hoursMinutes[1];


  //time3
  $time3 = $html_two->find('span[id=time3]',0)->plaintext;

  $hoursMinutes = explode(":", $time3[0]);
  $hours = $hoursMinutes[0];
  $minutes = $hoursMinutes[1];

  $time3 = explode(" ", $time3);
  $hoursMinutes = explode(":", $time3[0]);
  $hours = $hoursMinutes[0];
  $minutes = $hoursMinutes[1];
?>
```

Here is the time strings:

```
10:00 AM

11:00 AM

12:00 PM

12:30 PM

2:00 PM

2:30 PM

9:00 PM

11:00 PM

12:00 AM

12:30 AM

1:00 AM

1:30 AM

2:00 AM

11:00 PM

12:00 AM

12:30 AM

1:00 AM
```

**EDIT: Please see this for example what I want to achieve:**

```
10:00 AM - 20140424100000

11:00 AM - 20140424110000

12:00 PM - 20140424120000

12:30 PM - 20140424123000

2:00 PM - 20140424140000 

2:30 PM - 20140424143000

9:00 PM - 20140424210000

11:00 PM - 20140424230000 

12:00 AM - 20140425000000

12:30 AM - 20140425003000

1:00 AM - 20140425010000

1:30 AM - 20140425013000

2:00 AM - 20140425020000

11:00 PM - 20140425230000

12:00 AM - 20140426000000

12:30 AM - 20140426003000

1:00 AM - 20140426010000
```

Comment: Why don't you use unix epoch?

Comment: I don't know how to use it and I have got no idea how to work it out with $time1, $time2, $time3 variables. Can you help?

Comment: Sir, just to make sure .. which one is the input and the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

As you asked now we are converting the times to your format. based on the first element is today.

The key is to check if the conversion between PM - AM means day.

```
// Lets assume that we have this array of time strings. 
$array = array(
    "10:00 AM",
    "11:00 AM",
    "12:00 PM",
    "12:30 PM",
    "2:00 PM",
    "2:30 PM",
    "9:00 PM",
    "11:00 PM",
    "12:00 AM",
    "12:30 AM",
    "1:00 AM",
    "1:30 AM",
    "2:00 AM",
    "11:00 PM",
    "12:00 AM",
    "12:30 AM",
    "1:00 AM",
);

// Save the output format
$DATE_FORMAT_STRING = "Y m d H i s";

// function to get the state
function getState($string){
    $ex = explode(" ",$string);
    return $ex[1];
}

// GET the current STAGE
$current_state = getState($array[0]);
$offset = 0;
$values = array();

foreach($array as $time){

    // Get the item state.  
    $this_state = getState($time);

    // check if we past a day? 
    if($current_state == "PM" && $this_state == "AM"){
        $offset++;
    }

    $this_unix = strtotime($time) + (60 * 60 * 24 * $offset);

    $values[] = date($DATE_FORMAT_STRING, $this_unix);


    $current_state = $this_state;
}
```

This will output:

```
2014 04 24 10 00 00
2014 04 24 11 00 00
2014 04 24 12 00 00
2014 04 24 12 30 00
2014 04 24 14 00 00
2014 04 24 14 30 00
2014 04 24 21 00 00
2014 04 24 23 00 00
2014 04 25 00 00 00
2014 04 25 00 30 00
2014 04 25 01 00 00
2014 04 25 01 30 00
2014 04 25 02 00 00
2014 04 25 23 00 00
2014 04 26 00 00 00
2014 04 26 00 30 00
2014 04 26 01 00 00
```

Change `Y m d H i s` to `YmdHis` to get your exact format.

Comment: thank you very much for this, but the year, months, day and the hours that are random so how I can get the year, month, day and hours without I have to put in the $string variable?

Comment: I think you are confused what I'm trying to do. I want to check the time to get the date and when I have the 12:00 AM i want to set the new date format with the same date with following time and the next 12:00 AM i want to set up the new format with new date and time. The code you post it didn't make much sense.

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant. So do you want put the date next to the time when it past 24 hours?

Comment: Yes, I want to put the date next time when it past 24 hours in each time when it past the 12:00 AM with new date. how I can do that?

Comment: Are the dates ordered by recent or by oldest?

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by that, can you please tell me an example what do you mean?

Comment: so `foreach($html->find('p[id=links]') as $element)` is the element time the one before 1 hour ? or the first one that happened 5 days before? so you go from 01-02-2014 01:30 to 05-02-2014 01:30 or in reverse way ?

Comment: No, I want to get the hours to workout the format. Please see example i have updated in my first post.

Comment: Sir, just to make sure .. which one is the input and the output?

Comment: The first one is the output. And the second one is the input which I am showing you an example what I want to achieve.

Comment: so what is your input? `20140424100000` or `10:00 AM` ?

Comment: 10:00 AM is the output and the 20140424100000 is the input. Remember that the output I have for these time is random.

Comment: ARE YOU SURE ? your code is acting like `10:00 AM` is the input!!

Comment: yeah i am sure, sorry 10:00 AM is the input and the 20140424100000 is the output.

Comment: Then you need to specify the FIRST DATE .. for example the FIRST `10:00 AM` in WHAT day ? how do we know the date to start counting the days?

Comment: There are no date. I don't have the date, but I only the time. how can you workout to get the format using with the time?

Comment: That's impossible.. for example .. you give me the date of 08:00 AM ? you will never know .. I can do it by today, so the first element is 10:00 AM TODAY

Comment: yeah, the 10:00 AM is today. Can you make the next 10:00 AM is the next day using array if that is possible?

Comment: hope it's what you want.

Comment: yes it is correct and thank you very much for this which it much appreciated.

Comment: I have forgot to ask you a question. If I wish to use the value to get the strings `20140424160000` in the arrays, how I can do that? in what way i should use to echo?

Comment: use print_r to echo an array

Comment: I can only get the time, but I'm talking about get the format using the value. As for the code `$this_unix = strtotime($time) + (60 * 60 * 24 * $offset);` `echo date($DATE_FORMAT_STRING, $this_unix);`. How I can get the format using with the value?

Comment: here is the list of format in the input `20140424160000`, `20140424163000`, `20140424170000`, `20140424173000`, `20140424180000`, `20140424183000`, `20140424190000`. If i want to get the format `20140424183000` in the arrays using with the value, how i can do that?

Comment: Create an array and keep adding the value to it.. so in top $out = array(); then in the foreach $out[] = date(...)

Comment: can you please update the example code in your post as i'm bit lost. Sorry about that.

Comment: @user3494862 yes. all the values now are stored in an array